# sum of series whixh have two arithmetic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

> The sum of series
>
> $3+5+6+9+10+12+15+18+20+\cdots +100$ equals

what i try

the terms of series in not in arithmetic progression

so i am coupling it

$\bigg[(3+5)+(10+12)+(18+20)+\cdots +(98+100)\bigg]+\bigg[(6+9)+(15+18)+\cdots +(93+96)\bigg]$

$\bigg[8+22+38+\cdots 198\bigg]+\bigg[15+33+\cdots 189\bigg]$

again this series in not in arithmetic progression

How do i solve it help me please

Comment: What is the pattern in the sum? "$\dots$" makes sense only if the pattern is clear, here is isn't, it could be for example any of these https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C5%2C6%2C9%2C10%2C12%2C15%2C18%2C20&language=english&go=Search .... Although I would suspect the last one, i.e. numbers of form $n=3k$ or $n=5k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that after rearranging the terms, the sum consists of terms from

$A=3+6+9+12+...99$

$B=5,10,15,20,...100$

$A+B=\frac{(3+99)(33)}{2} +\frac{(5+100)(20)}{2}$

But some terms were double counted, for example $15,30,45...90$

$C=\frac{(15+90)(6)}{2}$

And finally,

$$A+B-C=1683+1050-315=2418$$

Comment: I was thinking like this, but not about double counting. Well done +1